# What is the exact meaning of 'emit' in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

The word **emit** is often used in Jetpack Compose's documentation or codelabs, as follows:

> The function doesn't return anything. Compose functions that "emit" UI do not need to return anything, because they describe the desired screen state instead of constructing UI widgets.

What is the exact meaning of **emit** in Android Jetpack Compose?

Who handles the UI emitted by the Compose function? Does the Compose framework detect and process the emitted UI?

Is there documentation with information on how and by whom the emitted UI is handled?

Comment: I believe the answer provided here would be helpful. [How compose works under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58558163/how-does-jetpack-compose-work-under-the-hood)

Comment: @javatar It's not a direct answer to the question, but thanks for a good article to understand the fundamentals of Compose :) I am trying to understand by watching the attached article and the video [Understanding Compose (Android Dev Summit '19)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9MtlmmN4Q0).

Comment: Just implies that it renders it out. If there are any handlers, they would be internal layers of the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Emit" means that Compose inserts a new group into the current composition.

See the [source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/runtime/runtime/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/Composables.kt;l=245?q=applier%20compose&start=21):

> ```
> @Suppress("NONREADONLY_CALL_IN_READONLY_COMPOSABLE", "UnnecessaryLambdaCreation")
> @Composable inline fun <T : Any, reified E : Applier<*>> ReusableComposeNode(
>     noinline factory: () -> T,
>     update: @DisallowComposableCalls Updater<T>.() -> Unit
> ) {
>     if (currentComposer.applier !is E) invalidApplier()
>     currentComposer.startReusableNode()   // <--- EMITTING THE NODE
>     if (currentComposer.inserting) {
>         currentComposer.createNode { factory() }
>     } else {
>         currentComposer.useNode()
>     }
>     currentComposer.disableReusing()
>     Updater<T>(currentComposer).update()
>     currentComposer.enableReusing()
>     currentComposer.endNode()
> }
> ```